# How to read a pixel depth value without stalling the pipeline?

Tags: opengl, optimization

Using glReadPixels on 1 single pixel stalls the pipeline even if I have swapped the buffers just before.
I don't need synchronization, I can do something like this:

```
pixel=DEFAULT_VALUE;
while (1){
    draw(pixel);
    swapBuffers();
    pixel=glRead???;
}
```

How can I do this in an optimized(not stalling) way?

Comment: Why do you need it? Getting data from the GPU is probably going to stall the pipeline no matter what you do.

Comment: I read the depth to get (after some calculations) the 3D world-space point that is "behind" the cursor.  My mesh is procedurally generated on the GPU, I cannot get that point without getting some value from the GPU.

Answer (score 4):

You can asynchronous pixel transfers via [Pixel Buffer Objects (PBOs)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/pixel_buffer_object.txt). When you issue a read call without PBOs, the pipeline is flushed and the CPU has to wait for the GPU to finish rendering and transfering the data. With PBOs, you provide a buffer in advance, and the data will be copied into that buffer when the GPU is ready, so it will not stall. It of course will stall when you try to access that buffer before it is ready (e.g. by `glGetBufferSubData()` or mapping that buffer for reading etc). So ideally, before reading back the data, you can queue up some other render commands, and also do some other CPU work, before accessing the buffer. The extension spec I linked has an example section, which is quite interesting.

This stuff can also be combined with [sync objects](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sync.txt). In that case, you can add a fence sync after the read call which will copy the data into the PBO. Then, on the CPU you can actually check if the operation is already completed. If not, you can do some other work and check back.

The main problem with all this asynchronous transfers is that you trade throughput for latency. So *if* you need that pixel value immediately, and do';t have any other work for the GPU and CPU which can be done inbetween, there is not much to gain. You then cannot really avoid the stalling, then.